# SendGrid implementation with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

We are using Heroku to host our Rails app, and are looking to send out our mail via `ActionMailer`. I just signed up for SendGrid, paid, and have a fully provisioned account ready to start firing off these emails. How should i go about implementing? through Heroku as an "add-on", or via the Rails documentation found on SendGrid's site?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the add-on, a new SendGrid account will be created with a randomly assigned username and password. Since you already have an account, you will need to reset the relevant Heroku environment variables to your existing credentials if you use the addon. Other than that, there should be no difference between letting Heroku generate the settings or doing it by hand.

Edit: Another difference is that if you use the addon, billing works a little differently. Heroku cannot currently bill overages, so if you are on a 40,000 email credits / month plan, that 40,000 is a hard limit. If your account is via SendGrid.com, it's a soft limit that allows you to pay overages if you send more mail.